# How to perform conditional aggregation AFTER groupby in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook, data-science

My 1st column is 'year'. My 2nd column is 'bank'. My last column is a "value".
I want to get the SUM of VALUE for year=2003 for each 'bank' and display that in a new column.
ie if my starting dataframe can be represented by the following code:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'year' : [2001, 2002, 2003, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2001, 2002, 2003],
               'bank' : ['sbi', 'sbi', 'sbi', 'sbi', 'sbi', 'sbi', 'icici', 'icici', 'icici', 'icici', 'icici', 'icici'],
                   'amt' : [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000,1,2,3,4,5,6]
                  })
```

Then the final output can be represented by the following code:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'year' : [2001, 2002, 2003, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2001, 2002, 2003],
                   'bank' : ['sbi', 'sbi', 'sbi', 'sbi', 'sbi', 'sbi', 'icici', 'icici', 'icici', 'icici', 'icici', 'icici'],
                       'amt' : [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000,1,2,3,4,5,6],
                       'amt_2003': [9000, 9000, 9000, 9000, 9000, 9000, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]
                      })
```

ie - For 'sbi', the total 'value' in 'year'=2003 is 3000+6000=9000, which is displayed against all rows for 'sbi'. Similarly, I get 9 against all rows of 'icici'.

I am unable to use the conditional sum after using a groupby('bank') statement.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by filtered rows for `2003` with aggregate `sum` for column `amt`:

```
df['amt_2003'] = df['bank'].map(df[df['year'].eq(2003)].groupby('bank')['amt'].sum())
```

Or use [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) for repalce non `2003` values to `0` and for new column use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['amt_2003'] = df['amt'].where(df['year'].eq(2003),0).groupby(df['bank']).transform('sum')
print (df)
    year   bank   amt  amt_2003
0   2001    sbi  1000      9000
1   2002    sbi  2000      9000
2   2003    sbi  3000      9000
3   2001    sbi  4000      9000
4   2002    sbi  5000      9000
5   2003    sbi  6000      9000
6   2001  icici     1         9
7   2002  icici     2         9
8   2003  icici     3         9
9   2001  icici     4         9
10  2002  icici     5         9
11  2003  icici     6         9
```

Fora all columns  use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) and [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df1 = (df.join(df.pivot_table(index='bank', columns='year',values='amt', aggfunc='sum')
                 .add_prefix('amt_'), on='bank'))
print (df1)
    year   bank   amt  amt_2001  amt_2002  amt_2003
0   2001    sbi  1000      5000      7000      9000
1   2002    sbi  2000      5000      7000      9000
2   2003    sbi  3000      5000      7000      9000
3   2001    sbi  4000      5000      7000      9000
4   2002    sbi  5000      5000      7000      9000
5   2003    sbi  6000      5000      7000      9000
6   2001  icici     1         5         7         9
7   2002  icici     2         5         7         9
8   2003  icici     3         5         7         9
9   2001  icici     4         5         7         9
10  2002  icici     5         5         7         9
11  2003  icici     6         5         7         9
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to perform a [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html), then [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df2 = df.groupby(['year', 'bank']).sum().unstack('year')
df2.columns = df2.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}')

out = df.merge(df2.reset_index())
```

Output:

```
    year   bank   amt  amt_2001  amt_2002  amt_2003
0   2001    sbi  1000      5000      7000      9000
1   2002    sbi  2000      5000      7000      9000
2   2003    sbi  3000      5000      7000      9000
3   2001    sbi  4000      5000      7000      9000
4   2002    sbi  5000      5000      7000      9000
5   2003    sbi  6000      5000      7000      9000
6   2001  icici     1         5         7         9
7   2002  icici     2         5         7         9
8   2003  icici     3         5         7         9
9   2001  icici     4         5         7         9
10  2002  icici     5         5         7         9
11  2003  icici     6         5         7         9
```

*NB. this works for more than just "amt" if you have several input columns.*

Intermediate `df2`:

```
       amt_2001  amt_2002  amt_2003
bank                               
icici         5         7         9
sbi        5000      7000      9000
```

To limit the years to keep, slice with [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
keep = [2003]

df2 = df.groupby(['year', 'bank']).sum().loc[keep].unstack('year')
df2.columns = df2.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}')

out = df.merge(df2.reset_index())
```

Output:

```
    year   bank   amt  amt_2003
0   2001    sbi  1000      9000
1   2002    sbi  2000      9000
2   2003    sbi  3000      9000
3   2001    sbi  4000      9000
4   2002    sbi  5000      9000
5   2003    sbi  6000      9000
6   2001  icici     1         9
7   2002  icici     2         9
8   2003  icici     3         9
9   2001  icici     4         9
10  2002  icici     5         9
11  2003  icici     6         9
```